# returning c string to a C# program

Tags: c#, c++, string, dll, export

I have a C++ dll that has a function that returns a c string and I have a C# program that calls this function and returns the data to a C# string. Here's what I mean

```
__declspec(dllexport) const char* function (const char* str) {
        std::string stdString( str );
        std::cout << stdString.c_str() << std::endl; // this prints fine, no data loss
        return stdString.c_str();
}
```

And here's the C# code

```
  [DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
  public static extern string function(string data);

  string blah = function("blah");
  Console.WriteLine(blah); // doesn't print anything...
```

When I look into the locals it says variable 'blah' is equal to "".

What happened to the data?

Comment: It got destroyed together with `stdString`.

Comment: C#'s `string` is not equivalent to `const char*`.

Comment: What would I use to return to a C# string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your C++ code is broken.  You are returning a pointer to a local variable.  It no longer exists after the function returns.  This tends to work by accident in a C++ program but is strong Undefined Behavior.  It cannot possibly work in an interop scenario, the pinvoke marshaler's use of the stack will overwrite the string.

A declaration that could work:

```
 void function (const char* str, char* output, size_t outputLength)
```

Use a StringBuilder in the [DllImport] declaration for the *output* argument and pass an initialized one with sufficient Capacity.

Comment: How do I convert my `std::string` values to `char*` values?

Comment: You already did in your original snippet.  But you have to *copy* the string to *output*.  Use strcpy_s().